# Magento 2 : Not assign simple product as associated in configurable products after migration from 1.8.0.0

Tags: migration, magento2.3.5, magento-1.8.1.0

I have migrated the store from Magento 1.8.0.0 to Magento 2.3.5 after checking Simple Products not assign as associated in configurable products. I also check in admin side configurable product, the associated products tab show blank.

[image]